# How well can IDLE be used without agreeing to ActiveState's ActiveTcl 8.6 license?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, activetcl

I am using IDLE for Python 3.2.5 on MAC OS 10.9, and when I open IDLE, it says

> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable. Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information.

When I go to that site, the OS X 10.9 instructions direct me to install ActiveTcl [from ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads). When I click on the bit Download button near the top right, it downloads a .dmg with a license file that includes the following: "ACTIVESTATE reserves the right to change this Agreement at any time, which change shall be effective immediately upon the posting on ACTIVESTATE'S website ...". Accordingly, I will not be installing that program from ActiveState.

Is there any other way to address the possible stability issue(s)? (Such a way may include getting a version of Tcl/Tk from somewhere other than ActiveState, and/or changing to a different version of IDLE.)

Comment: Python itself does not rely on Tcl at all - that's just for IDLE (the editor), which you don't have to use, as any other text editor will do fine.

Comment: @voithos: I just fixed the question.

Comment: @voithos: On the other hand, I previously did not know that Tcl was only needed for running Python _through IDLE_.

Comment: Are you particularly interested in using IDLE? If not, I would recommend simply not using it.

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing.

Comment: To be clear, Tcl/Tk isn't needed at all for "running Python through IDLE".  Tcl/Tk is needed *for* IDLE itself:  IDLE's windows are implemented as Tcl/Tk objects.  Other than that, as @voithos said, almost nothing in a standard Python distribution uses Tcl/Tk at all (e.g., I think `turtle.py` uses it - but nothing uses `turtle.py` ;-) ).  BTW, IDLE uses little of Tcl/Tk's full functionality - I'd be surprised if the supposed instabilities made any real difference for using IDLE.

Comment: take a look at pycharm community edition, eclipse, ninja(or almost any other IDE you want) as all are much better python IDE's than IDLE ... and I think they are all multiplatform ... @TimPeters awww turtle.py is so nostalgic though ... evokes memories of my first graphical computer program :P

Comment: @Tim, be surprised. For example, don't try typing in any composite characters in an IDLE (or other Tk) text field using the Apple-supplied Tk 8.5.   http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#apple-8-5-9

Comment: You don't need no stinkin' IDE -- all a real Python programmer needs is a decent text editor and an open terminal window. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care to be bound by the ActiveState license, you could try to build a framework build of Tcl 8.5 and Tk 8.5 yourself; be aware, though, that [for OS X 10.9](http://bugs.python.org/issue19373) you'll need to apply [a patch from Tk trunk](http://core.tcl.tk/tk/tktview?name=53f7a1b553) to the most recent Tk release, 8.5.15.  You could also use a Python from [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) which uses its own version of Tk and has the above patch.  Or you could risk using the Apple-supplied Tk in 10.9 and be really careful about what you type so that it doesn't crash with no chance at recovery.  In future releases, the plan is for the python.org OS X installers to install their own version of Tcl/Tk if necessary.

Also note that the Python you are using is linked with Tk 8.5.  Installing a newer version of Tk 8.6 won't make any difference; you need to install a newer version of Tk 8.5.

By the way, Python 3.2.5 is obsolete and is no longer actively supported.  Consider [installing a current Python 3 version](http://www.python.org/download/), at the moment, 3.3.3.  Come to think of it, if you are using the python.org 3.2.5 64-bit OS X version, you'll very likely to run into a [10.9 crash problem when using the interpreter interactively](http://bugs.python.org/issue18458).  This problem is fixed in 3.3.3 (and 2.7.6).